# LightSwitch vs WinForms

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-lightswitch

What is the difference between Visual Studio LightSwitch and WinForms? 
Why we should choose one over the other?

Update: I understand that LightSwitch is an application framework.  May be the better question is, how a LighSwitch application compares to a windows forms application built with Composite Application Block (CAB)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lightswitch is a template driven application development environment for Visual Studio.  It creates Silverlight applications that use a View-Model architecture, using Entity Framework and RIA services for data access.

The applications can be run locally on the desktop with a local data store, or with a data store on a server, or run in a browser with a data store on a server.

The Lightswitch framework includes designers to create and manage most aspects of an business application such as:

- Data model with validation and relationships
- Screens
- Menus
- Queries
- As of Beta 1, there is no built-in reporting engine

It's scope remains to be seen, but I believe it's targeted for development of corporate in-house applications, such as CMS systems, billing systems, etc. and also line-of-business applications, small and large scale.

WinForms or Windows Forms is the graphical API for .NET that lets you create user interfaces with forms and controls, etc.  It's not a complete application development framework.

This thread compares LightSwitch to building line-of-business applications in Silverlight today:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/lightswitchgeneral/thread/3f6161b6-33a3-4b6a-a4d8-ea693d6ba273

This video gives a high-level overview of LightSwitch
http://www.microsoft.com/showcase/en/us/details/74ed35cb-709b-46f7-8b21-2f681965ed0b

Answer (score 1):

Sorry Carlos, but LightSwitch does **not** generate either WinForms, or WebForms projects. The only official client technology is a Silverlight client, whether it is a web application, or a desktop (OOB) application.

In the very early days, I believe the client was originally WPF, but that was changed to SilverLight some time ago.

While LS *does* "generate" code, it does so for its own use, not for consumption external to LS.

Answer (score 0):

One imortant distinction between Lightswitch and Composite Application Block UI, is that CAB has been retired and is no longer developed.

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480450.aspx